# Why stored procedure is not giving output in one string and the stored procedure executed on MySql 6.0 gives error on MySql 5.0

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, plsql

I have following table structure

```
id     |      Name     | senior id

1      |   superadmin  |  -1
2      |   abc         |   1     
3      |   xyz         |   1
4      |   pqr         |   2   
5      |   vwx         |   3
6      |   stu         |   3
7      |   efg         |   4
8      |   ijk         |   3
9      |   nop         |   3
10     |   rst         |   3
11     |   uvw         |   9
```

Here I Wrote a stored procedure which takes id as a input and will return a string of concatanated names seperated by '/' from the name associated with id to the name whose seniorid is -1.

for example if I pass the id as 10 to SP I will expect the return string as 
`rst/xyz/superadmin/`

Here is the stored procedure that I have written

```
DELIMITER $$;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`get_list_up_to_senior`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_list_up_to_senior`(id int (8))

BEGIN
DECLARE strsenior VARCHAR(250);
DECLARE strseniorlist VARCHAR(250);
DECLARE temp int(8);
SET strsenior =  '';
SET strseniorlist = '';
SET temp = id;
WHILE temp  != -1 DO
   SET  strsenior = (SELECT name FROM mydb.tblname WHERE id = temp limit 1);
   SET  temp = (SELECT seniorid FROM mydb.tblname WHERE id = temp limit 1);
   SET  strseniorlist = CONCAT(strseniorlist,strsenior,'/');
END WHILE;

SELECT strseniorlist;
END$$

DELIMITER ;$$
```

When I compiles this SP I get compiles with no error. But when I execute this SP; its get executed perfectly and returns

```
strseniorlist
superadmin/
```

1)What is wrong in my SP so that I am not getting desired output.

My database version is MySQL 6.0 and I am using Sqlyog to execute above SP.

2)When I execute the above SP on MySql 5.0 Its not get created and gives following errors

```
ERROR :

(0 row(s) affected)
(0 ms taken)

Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PROCEDURE `get_list_up_to_senior`(id int (8))

BEGIN
DECLARE strsenior VA' at line 1
(16 ms taken)
```

Please guide me friends in this to solve the problems 
Thank You!

Comment: The latest version of MySQL is 5.6. Please double check your software versions and edit your question.

Comment: @OllieJones Thank You Sir for your reply, I am sure about MySql Software version and it is 6.0.11. I have downloaded it from this URL http://downloads.mysql.com/archives.php?p=mysql-6.0                       I have downloaded installer for Microsoft Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause and answer to my first question. 
The reason behind not getting the expected output is that I have use a user define variable name 'id' as incoming parameter to SP. This variable name 'id' is similar to the column name of the table that I mentioned. So MySql is considering this 'id' as local variable and not the  table column. The conflict is here. If you change the incoming parameter variable name to SP to something else which will not conflict to the column names in mentioned tables in the queries. You will get the desired output.

Thank You!